# Def of Sheaf on Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In hartshorne, for a ring $A$, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ on Spec $A$ is defined to be a map sending each open set $U$ of Spec $A$ into the set of functions $s: U \to \coprod _{p \in U} A_\frak{p}$ such that $s(\frak{p})$ $ \in A_{\frak{p}}$ for each $\frak{p} \in U $ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $\frak{o}$  contained in $U$ and elements $a,f \in A$ such that for each $\frak{q} \in V$, $f \notin q$ and $s(\frak{q}$ $)=a/f \in A_{\frak{q}}$.

If we define the reduced  scheme $\mathcal{O
}_{red}$ on Spec $A$ such that it sends each open set of $U$ to the quotient of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ by its ideal of nilpotent elements, then can we say that $\mathcal{O}_{red}(U)$ is the set of functions $s: U \to \coprod _{p \in U} B_\frak{p}$ such that $s(\frak{p})$ $ \in B_{\frak{p}}$, where $B$ is the quotient of $A$ by its ideal of nipotent elements? If so, why? I cannot give any plain proof.

*hartshorne page 79 for the definition of reduced scheme.*

---

This is a problem of the following  (Harsthorne page 79 2.3.)

> Reduced Schemes. A scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is reduced if for every
>   open set $U \subset X$, the ring $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ has no nilpotent
>   elements.
>
> (a) Show that $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is reduced if for every $P \in X$,
>   the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ has no nilpotent elements.

I proved this via contraposition.
Suppose that there is an element $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ such that $s^n =0 \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. Then the element $<U,s>$ defines a germ at some $p \in U$. Since $s^n=0 \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, the germ $<U,s>$  defined a nilpotent element of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$, thus the statement (a) follows.

> (b) Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}$ be a scheme. Let $(\mathcal{O})_{red}$ be
>   the sheaf associated to the presheaf $U \mapsto
>  (\mathcal{O}_{X}(U))_{red}$, where we denote by $
>  (\mathcal{O}_{X}(U))_{red}$ the quotient of  $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ by
>   the nilradical.
>
> Show that $X_{red}:=(X,(\mathcal{O}_{X})_{red}$ is a
>   scheme.  We call it the *reduced scheme associated t*o $X$, and denote 
>   $X_{red}$.
>
> Show that there is a moprhism of schemes $X_{red} \to X$ which
>   is a homeomorphism on the underlying topological spaces.

To prove this, I am not sure what should I prove.

For simplicity, I restrict the problem to the case of a spectrum.

Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a spectrum of a ring $A$.

For an arbitrary ring $B$, we denote by $B_{red}$ the quotient space by the nilradical .

**We prove that the reduced spectrum of $(X,\mathcal{O})$ is a spectrum of a ring $A_{red}$.**

Then, first I consider a open set of the from $D(f)$ where $f \in A$.
Then by definition,

$\mathcal{O}_{red}(D(f))= (A_f)_{red}$.

Now, we show that

1) $(A_f)_{red} = (A_{red})_f$,

2) there is an homeomorphism $(A_f)_{red}  \supset D([f]) \to D(f) \subset A$,
where $[f]$ denotes the equivalence class of $f$ in $(A_f)_{red}$.

First, we prove statement (2).
 We note that any prime ideal contains the nilradical In fact, let $x$ be nilpotent element the ring $A$, then there is a positive number $n$ such that $x^n=0$. Then any prime ideal $\frak{p}$ it follows that $\frak{p} \ni 0 = x^n$, thus $x \in \frak{p}$.

This implies that the map  $(A_f)_{red}  \supset D([f]) \to D(f) \subset A$ is bijective. (homeo is remained).　Now I proceed the proof of

1) $(A_f)_{red} = (A_{red})_f$.

Let $\frak{n}$ be a nilradical.

Then there is an exact sequence.

$0 \to \frak{n}$$ \to A\to A_{red} \to 0$.

Applying the localization operator $S^{-1}$ at $f \in A$,

$0 \to S^{-1}\frak{n}$$ \to S^{-1}A\to S^{-1}A_{red} \to 0$.

This means

$0 \to S^{-1}\frak{n}$$ \to A_f \to (A_{red})_{[f]} \to 0$.

where $[f]$ is an equivalence class of  $f$ in $A_{red}$.
Because $S^{-1}\frak{n}$ is the nilradical of $ A_f $, the last short exact sequence implies that  $(A_f)_{red} = (A_{red})_f$.

UNDER CONSTRUCTION

Comment: "by its deal of nilpotent element" ? I don't understand the word "deal" in the context.

Comment: I mistype. It is ideal.

Comment: The definition of a sheaf  you gave above sounds more like a property of sheaves to me. eg Gathmann defines a sheaf to be a presheaf that has a glueing property.

Comment: The only thing you need to know is that nilradical commutes with localization.